# Join 3D points into a 3D line in QGIS (with Qgis2threejs plugin)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a series of several points in a csv, with each row being a different point, with information for various attributes, including the x and y coordinates, stored across the columns. I've been able to display these points in 3D with the Qgis2threejs plugin, using one of the columns in the csv as the elevation.

How would I go about creating a line which joins each of these points in order, and retains the elevation information for each of them (and preferably also the other attribute information)? I've tried using the 'points to path' tool in the processing toolbox, but this just returns a line which, whilst joining all the points, only has one row in its attribute table, listing the beginning and the end of the line, and loses all other information. If it would be easier I would be fine creating several separate lines, one joining each of the points, but there are 82 rows in the csv (ie 82 points), so I'd have to have a way to do this automatically. Ultimately I'm looking to have a line (or lines) joining the points in 3D, presumably also displayed using Qgis2threejs.

I'm running QGIS 3.4.4 on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Let me split your question into two sections

1. Assign attributes to the line
   Problem here is that you create a single line, one object, with one set of attributes. The vertices of the line aren't equal to the 82 points in this regard. The vertices of the line don't have their own attribute table as the points in the point layer do, therefore you can't keep all the attribute information (somebody correct me please if I'm wrong).
   You can of course draw a line for every set of two points, but then you still need to decide to either assign the attribute values of either the begin or end point. A nice way to do this automatically is through "joins" under the Layer Properties.
2. Create a line connecting points in 3D
   At the moment your points are 2D (xy) with a elevation value in the attribute table. To draw 3D-lines between the points you should convert them into 3D (xyz) points:

Convert point layer into a pointZ layer ([Assign z values to depth curves in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274091/assign-z-values-to-depth-curves-in-qgis))
A. select "Set Z value" from Processing Toolbox
B. click on the data defined override button right of the Z value field (see picture), go to field type and select the field with the elevation/z data.
C. run and save the newly created z value enabled point layer (this process preserves all attribute values)

Then you can use, as you did, the 'points to path' tool in the processing toolbox. Applied on the z value enabled point layer (pointZ layer) it will automatically create a z value enabled linestring layer (lineStringZ layer) that will display fine in Qgis2threejs.
If you choose to draw a line from point to point by snapping to the points, it will work in 3D too. The snapping will take the xyz values from the 3D-points for generating the geometry of the line. Important, when you create the line layer don't forget to toggle the "include Z dimension" box, otherwise the z value of the point geometries will not be taken over.

Hope it's understandable and helps somewhat.