# How to get QGIS to make 3D mesh (triangles or quads) from points with 3D coordinates?

Tags: qgis, 3d, mesh

I have random added points with height.
GeoJSON looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "randompoint_Zadded",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "rand_point_id": 0, "id": 4261, "height": -50, "biome": 0, "type": "lake", "state": 0, "culture": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -90.054842781105137, -4.86885276816724, -50.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "rand_point_id": 1, "id": 4399, "height": -50, "biome": 0, "type": "lake", "state": 0, "culture": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -89.194361044666223, -8.170296543553695, -50.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "rand_point_id": 2, "id": 8, "height": 3, "biome": 11, "type": "island", "state": 11, "culture": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -123.768371068997496, 89.425974999614226, 3.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "rand_point_id": 3, "id": 9, "height": 3, "biome": 11, "type": "island", "state": 11, "culture": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -121.593218898593122, 89.894122960381807, 3.0 ] } },
...
```

But when I try triangulation (Delaunay), I get 4 groups of 2 coordinates and no more elevation:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POINTA": 1834.0, "POINTB": 1121.0, "POINTC": 491.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 66.443159419272476, -90.16857229914234 ], [ 69.674875637412129, -90.199714898494094 ], [ 62.575105683814591, -90.542588929594473 ], [ 66.443159419272476, -90.16857229914234 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POINTA": 1121.0, "POINTB": 1120.0, "POINTC": 491.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 69.674875637412129, -90.199714898494094 ], [ 56.65853796364302, -91.015383266865882 ], [ 62.575105683814591, -90.542588929594473 ], [ 69.674875637412129, -90.199714898494094 ] ] ] } },
```

Note: This is not Earth but an another type of map, I don't have raster height map for it.

How to get some 3D mesh from QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

1st: convert your imported GeoJSON point layer into a pointZ layer ([Assign z values to depth curves in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274091/assign-z-values-to-depth-curves-in-qgis))

- A. select "`Set Z value`" from Processing Toolbox
- B. click on the `data defined override` button right of the Z value
  field (see picture), go to field type and select the field with the
  elevation/height/z data.
- C. run and save the newly created z value enabled point layer.

2nd: 3D-points can be made into triangulated surfaces by the GRASS `v.delaunay` tool. A xy-polygon layer is automatically created by the GRASS tool and named "`Delaunay triangulation`". The layer has z-values in the geometry but is set to a xy-polygon layer and therefore won't right away display in 3D. Export this layer to a polygon layer with included z-dimension (check box under geometry in the save vector layer as... dialogue) and the exported xyz-polygon layer will display in 3D.

You end up with a polygon layer with xyz-coordinates. If you want to create a mesh, then use the "`TIN Mesh Creation`" from the Mesh tools on your xyz-points and check the "`Use Z-coordinate for Value on Vertex`" box. I don't know how this will display in the 3D Map View, it won't display in Qgis2threejs Exporter.

Careful: The vector geometry tool "`Delaunay triangulation`" won't keep the z-coordinate, use the GRASS tool.

Note: When you convert a set of three points (with three sets of attributes) to one surface (with three vertices and one set of attributes) you will loose the attributes of the points. When you look at the geometry of the triangulated surfaces you see 4 groups of coordinates because the last point is the same as the first, in order to close the polygon).